# Which XML serialization library for Scala?

Tags: xml, serialization, scala, xml-serialization

I'm looking for xml serialization library for scala.
For json serialization I use lift-json, and would like my xml serialization library to be similar, that means:

- automatic serialization of case classes (without any format definition)
- smart serialization of scala types: collections, options etc.
- ability to define formats for other datatypes to adjust a way they are serialized
- deserialization not based on implicits but rather on class name (sometimes I have only class/class name of type which must be deserialized)

Do you know if such library exists?

Answer (score 5):

One great alternative is to use the pure Java library [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org).

This works with case classes out of the box, with some tweaking - I'm using the class [XStreamConversions](http://code.google.com/p/mixedbits-webframework/source/browse/trunk/src/main/scala/net.mixedbits.tools/XStreamConversions.scala) from [mixedbits-webframework](http://code.google.com/p/mixedbits-webframework/) -, it also works with List, Tuple, Symbol, ListBuffer and ArrayBuffer. So it's not perfect, but you can surely fine tune it for your specific needs.
Here is a small example.

```
    import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream
    import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxDriver
    import net.mixedbits.tools.XStreamConversions

    case class Bar(a:String)
    case class Foo(a:String,b:Int,bar:Seq[Bar])

    object XStreamDemo {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
            val xstream = XStreamConversions(new XStream(new StaxDriver()))
            xstream.alias("foo", classOf[Foo])
            xstream.alias("bar", classOf[Bar])
            val f0 = Foo("foo", 1, List(Bar("bar1"),Bar("bar2")))

            val xml = xstream.toXML(f0)
            println(xml)

            val f1 = xstream.fromXML(xml)
            println(f1)
            println(f1 == f0)
      }
    }
```

This produces the following output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?><foo><a>foo</a><b>1</b><bar class="list"><bar><a>bar1</a></bar><bar><a>bar2</a></bar></bar></foo>
    Foo(foo,1,List(Bar(bar1), Bar(bar2)))
    true
```

For Java 1.6 / Scala 2.9 the dependencies are the xstream.jar file and the mentioned XStreamConversions class.

Comment: Bad thing about this method is lack of handling of `Option[]`

Answer (score 4):

Try [**scalaxb**](http://scalaxb.org/)

Comment: Scalaxb coverts xsd files to scala classes. But I have scala classes and would like to serialize them.