# mutually recursive types in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Is it possible to have mutual recursive types in scala?

I have a xml files with a list of bugtracker issues. It's raw data. The model has different issue-types like "tasks", "subtasks", "bug", "special-bug".

Now I want to parse my raw-data to a hierarchical structure of tasks and subtasks:

```
// data type for field contents
abstract class Field
case class Id(raw : string) extends Field
case class Status(raw : string) extends Field
...

// data type for primary model
abstract class Issue(id : String, ...)
case class Task(id : Id, status : Status ..., subtasks : List[Subtask] ) extends Issue(id, ...)
case class Subtask(id : Id, status : Status ..., parent: Task) extends Issue(id, ...)
```

I wonder if this mutual recursion is theoretically possible?

Second question:

I render the model to some wiki-markup. This works fine with an overloaded recursive render() : String in the class for the datatype. (Probably I should have a "Renderable" Superclass !?)

What would be the cleanest way for parsing, i.e. I'd like to have a recursive

```
fromXML : scala.xml.Elem => Issue / Field
```

Where would I put it? How would it look like? IIUC, the companion is autogenerated for case-classes so I cant add to it?

I have this e.g.:

```
def fromXml(e : Elem) = e match {
  case <a>test</a> => Id("test") 
  case _ => Status("Pre-analysed")
}
```

But I failed to give the function a type. What *is* the type of that function ?

I also thought about passing the xml-elem directly to the constructor of the ADT, would that be clever? Or should I separate XML-parsing and model-creation ?

---

Jesus, after learning the scala basics and doing some scripts and functions (and thinking too much java), I finally understood how to write ADTs and can express myself nearly as in good old Haskell times :-)

Comment: You should improve the structure of your question to make it clearer what your overall goals are; try to group your subquestions in a meaningful way (I did not downvote you).

Comment: @mhs: yes, you are right, I jsut wrote down the open ends of my project. Nevermind, your answer helps to get further ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A:** Regarding the initialisation of immutable, mutually dependent classes, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507965/instantiating-immutable-paired-objects).

**B:** Regarding your question `render: Foo => String` function vs. `Renderable` superclass, this is IMHO more or less a design decision between a functional and an object-oriented approach. I personally don't think that one of them is superior to the other, it is just a matter of taste. The paper ["Independently Extensible Solutions to the Expression Problem"](http://scala-lang.org/docu/files/IC_TECH_REPORT_200433.pdf) has a nice comparison between the two, although in a slightly more elaborate context (it is a great read, however).

**C:** Companion objects are created by the compiler, but if you also specify a companion object, the compiler will merge the two.

**D:** In your current class hierarchy there is no non-trivial common supertype for `Issue` and `Field`, which makes it difficult to give a meaningful return type for `fromXML`. You could work with an `Either[Issue, Field]`, though, but this looks fishy to me. In general, I would avoid mixing functions that are supposed to return full-fledged nodes (e.g., `Task`) with those that return "internal" nodes (e.g., `Status`).

**E:** Did you had a look at existing solutions, e.g. [scalaxb](http://scalaxb.org/)? You can find more links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967160/which-xml-serialization-library-for-scala) and [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10774).

Comment: concerning D: I see, but I already had problems with only the Field type. when I write fromXML(e : Elem) : Field, the match gives me incompatible types Field <-> Id, which I dont udnerstand since Id is a subclass of Field (in the OO sense). What's the (return) type of that function ?