# Recursive Types in Scala with a List

Tags: scala, case-class, recursive-datastructures

Similarly to [mutually recursive types in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834928/mutually-recursive-types-in-scala) I am trying to create a mutually recursive type in Scala.

I am trying to make a graph defined with this type (which does compile) :

```
 case class Node(val id : Int, val edges : Set[Node])
```

But I don't understand how I can actually create something with this type, because in order to initialize Node A with edges B and C, I need to at least have  a lazy reference to B and C, but I can't simultaneously create their edgesets.

Is it possible to implement this recursive type?

EDIT:

Here is the solution I am currently using to convert an explicit adjacency list to a self-referential one.

```
def mapToGraph(edgeMap : Map[Int, mutable.Set[Int]]) : List[Node] = {
  lazy val nodeMap = edgeMap map  (kv => (kv._1, new Node(kv._1, futures.get(kv._1).get)))
  lazy val futures : Map[Int, Set[Node]] = edgeMap map (kv => {
    val edges = (kv._2 map (e => nodeMap.get(e).get)).toSet
    (kv._1, edges)
  })
  val eval = nodeMap.values.toList
  eval //to force from lazy to real - don't really like doing this
}
```

or alternatively, fromm an edgelist

```
//reads an edgeList into a graph
def readEdgelist(filename : String) : List[Node] = {
  lazy val nodes = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Node]()
  lazy val edges = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.Buffer[Node]]()
  Source.fromFile(filename).getLines() filter (x => x != None) foreach {edgeStr =>
    val edge = edgeStr.split('\t')
    if (edge.size != 2) goodbye("Not a well-formed edge : " + edgeStr + " size: " + edge.size.toString)
    val src = edge(0).toInt
    val des = edge(1).toInt
    if (!(nodes.contains(src))) nodes.put(src, new Node(src, futures.get(src).get))
    if (!(nodes.contains(des))) nodes.put(des, new Node(des, futures.get(des).get))
    edges.put(src, edges.getOrElse(src, mutable.Buffer[Node]()) += nodes.get(des).get)
  }
  lazy val futures : Map[Int, Set[Node]] = nodes map {node => (node._1, edges.getOrElse(node._1, mutable.Buffer[Node]()).toSet)} toMap
  val eval = nodes.values.toList
  eval
}
```

Thanks everyone for the advice!

Comment: `val` declarations in case classes are redundant

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize and "modify" a cyclic persistent data structure in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682277/how-to-initialize-and-modify-a-cyclic-persistent-data-structure-in-scala)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to work from the bottom up

```
val b = Node(1, Set.empty)
val c = Node(2, Set.empty)
val a = Node(3, Set(b, c))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Bottom-up doesn't help if the edges are not directed or if there are cycles in the graph.

Comment: Further, suppose you won't to make a much larger graph. Consider that you have an edgeList in the form List[(Int, Int)] - you no longer hold a reference to every Node, right?

Answer (score 3):

Chicken & egg... you have three options:

1. Restrict your graphs to Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAGs) and use RKumsher's suggestion.
2. To retain immutability, you'll need to separate your node instances from your edge sets (two different classes: create nodes, then create edge sets/graph).
3. If you prefer the tight correlation, consider using a setter for the edge sets so that you can come back and set them later, after all the nodes are created.

Comment: A solution based on the the lazy chicken/egg reference requires explicit code to create each chicken/egg (each lazy reference); It isn't suitable for bulk-loading loosely structured (i.e. variable # of nodes & # edges per node) data from, say, a file.